# How an Angular $watch to indentity how the $scope.value changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have a watch for a variable. $scope.value

I have two possiblility to update my value.

- One is from my controller eg..through any services.
- Other is any input event can update my $scope.value. By keypress ect..

I need to identify from were the update is occured from my watch.

```
$scope.$watch('value',function(){
       //how to identify from were my actual change occured.   
 });
```

Comment: I need to identify from were the actuall change occured. ??

Comment: You can track the changes made directly in your input using ng-change (like this: <input ng-model="modelField" ng-change="changedInput(modelField)" )directive, and track service changes with $watch service.

Comment: So there is no any direct method.

Comment: No directly, because $watch pass to your listener function just old and new values as parameters. You can control with a variable (weird solution) or ng-change, that tracks changes made in the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in or easy or standard way to do this.

You may:

- Set a temporary variable to indicate the change source, e.g.

  ```
  var sourceOfChange;
  myService.doSomething().then(function() {
      sourceOfChange = 'myService';
      $scope.value = ...
  });
  $scope.$watch('value',function() {
      if( sourceOfChange === 'myService' ) {
          ...
      }
      ...
  });
  ```
- Update *different* variables per source, watch those variables and do the source-specific processing, and finally update the `value`, e.g.:

  ```
  // initialization
  $scope.value = ...
  $scope.valueFromInput = $scope.$value;
  $scope.valueFromService = $scope.$value;

  // watching the source-specific values
  $scope.$watch('valueFromInput', function(newval) {
      doInputSpecificProcessing(newval);
      $scope.value = newval;
  });

  // watch the value and do common processing
  $scope.$watch('value', doCommonProcessing);
  ```
- There can also be other ways